# Convert values of a tensor in TensorFlow to regular Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tensorflow.js, vector-multiplication

I used the outerProduct function in the TensorFlow.js framework on two 1D arrays (a,b), but I am finding it difficult to get the values of the resulting tensor in the regular javascript format.

Even after using .dataSync and Array.from(), I am still unable to get the expected output format. The resulting outer product between the two 1D arrays should give one 2D array, but I am getting 1D array instead.

```
const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2]);
const b = tf.tensor1d([3, 4]);
const tensor = tf.outerProduct(b, a);
const values = tensor.dataSync();
const array1 = Array.from(values);
```

console.log(array1);

The expected result is array1 = [ [ 3, 6 ] , [ 4, 8 ] ], but I am getting 
array1 = [ 3, 6, 4, 8 ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Version < 15**

The result of `tf.data` or `tf.dataSync` is always a flatten array. But one can use the shape of the tensor to get a multi-dimensional array using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const x = tf.tensor3d([1, 2 , 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 4, 1]);

x.print()

// flatten array
let arr = x.dataSync()

//convert to multiple dimensional array
shape = x.shape
shape.reverse().map(a => {
  arr = arr.reduce((b, c) => {
  latest = b[b.length - 1]
  latest.length < a ? latest.push(c) : b.push([c])
  return b
}, [[]])
console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**From version 0.15**

One can use [tensor.array()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.1/#tf.Tensor.array) or [tensor.arraySync()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.1/#tf.Tensor.array)

Answer (score 2):

As of tfjs version 0.15.1 you can use `await tensor.array()` to get the nested array.

Answer (score 0):

you can take your `values`  and do something like

```js
const values = [3, 6, 4, 8];

let array1 = []

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
  array1.push([values[i], values[i + 1]])
}

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: thanks. I am trying to generalize your suggestion to n-element in a and m-element in b arrays, that will give a 2D array of n x m. I have figured out that the 2 increment is the number of columns, in this case it will be the number of elements in a; but would have to add array1(i+m-1) times, which will not make the code dynamic. Do you know how to make it more dynamic?  For example consider this modification to the above code: const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3]);
const b = tf.tensor1d([3, 4]); const tensor = tf.outerProduct(b, a).

Comment: The for loop becomes:                                                                                            
 for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i += 3) {
  res.push([array1[i], array1[i + 1], array1[i + 2]])
}

Comment: you can just make a dynamic  increment instead of 2 :)

Comment: If I adjust the increment, I will still need to add more arguments to push manually =>([array1[i], array1[i + 1], array1[i + 2], array1[i+3]...,array1[i+m-2], array1[i+m-1]]). That's the issue.